Flutter 3.24.4 creates instability on launching Simulator
I have upgraded my development environment to Flutter 3.24.4 and upgraded Xcode&Swift alongside. After fixing dependency problems, I have deleted all the caches and derived data etc. to make sure everything is ok.
Here is my flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on macOS 15.1 24B83 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at /Users/zahidtekbas/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 603104015d (3 weeks ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
    • Engine revision db49896cf2
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/zahidtekbas/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/zahidtekbas/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16B40
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.100.0

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

The problem is,
Sometimes, Xcode unable to launch Runner and gives me this error:
Launching lib/main_dev.dart on iPhone 16 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         9.4s
Xcode build done.                                           48.4s
Error: Unable to launch com.example.app.dev on 03F89113-0F77-4181-B313-DE59A6028C12:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 1:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
Simulator device failed to launch com.example.app.dev.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
        The request to open "com.example.app.dev" failed.
        The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl launch 03F89113-0F77-4181-B313-DE59A6028C12 com.example.app.dev --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode
  --verify-entry-points
Error launching application on iPhone 16.

The environment was working perfectly before upgrading Flutter & Swift. When it does not work, I just do another flutter run and it works, somehow. I don't even run pub clean & pub get. It just works.
I don't know the underlying issue. Can it be really related to FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain? Does anyone encounter this kind of issue after upgrading Flutter SDK to 3.24.4?
